# Is a proof "The diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other" without using concept of "congruence of angles" still correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I post my proof in pictures below and I am not sure if my proof correct?

This is an exercise from section 1.1 of the classical textbook **linear algebra** by Stephen Friedberg etc

> Prove that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.

I choose to use words and ideas from this section as possible as I can to prove that exercise.

And surfing on the internet I found that other ways of this proof use concept of "congruence of angles"

Is a proof "The diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other" without using concept of "congruence of angles" still correct?

Comment: You are correct. The fact that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other requires no concept of angle. If you apply any linear transformation to a parallelogram, it remains a parallelogram and the diagonals still bisect, even though the angles have all changed. A proof using linear algebra but not the dot product confirms this. Geometric properties like this are called affine geometric in contrast to properties that require the dot product (or lengths and angles), which are called Euclidean geometric.

Comment: You've posted your own proof as an answer, but tagged "solution verification". Surely the question should contain the proof, and an answer should be an explanation of whether the proof is correct? Anyway, your proof looks correct - that $u + \tfrac{1}{2}(v-u) = \tfrac{1}{2} (v+u)$.

Comment: I was so anxious for real. I thought I was so dumb. Becluse I looked through various different ways of proving this exercise on internet. Some people write a whole solution manual of this textbook which uses the concept of **congruence of angles**, even khan academy approaches this exercise in a way similar to **congruence of angles**.

Comment: All Your replies encourage me. thx.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that doesn't use angle congruences, using vectors instead.

Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ span the parallelogram.

The diagonal between the points $a$ and $b$ is described by $t\vec a + (1-t)\vec b,\quad 0\le t\le 1$, and it's midpoint at $t=\frac12$ is also the midpoint of the other diagonal by symmetry.

Comment: The term (1-t) multiplies vector b. Why is that? and is my proof correct?

Comment: @StatsCruncher; I forgot to add the boundary for $t$. Its the equation of a line segment. Your proof looks fine.

Comment: (vector b) + t*(vector a - vector b)

Comment: how do you use the symmetry? seems handwavey

Comment: @user253751; rotational symmetry of $180^{\circ}$ about the midpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a standard proof based on my experience with vectors.

Let $\ WXYZ\ $ be the vertices of a paralellogram, in clockwise order, and let $\ P\ $ be the point of intersection of the diagonals $\ WY\ $ and $\ XZ.$

$\ \exists\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}:\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{WP} = \lambda \overset{\longrightarrow}{WY} = \lambda\left( \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY}\right)\qquad (1) $

$\ \exists\ \mu\in\mathbb{R}:\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{XP} = \mu \overset{\longrightarrow}{XZ} = \mu\left( \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY} + \overset{\longrightarrow}{YZ}\right) \implies \overset{\longrightarrow}{WP} =  \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \overset{\longrightarrow}{XP}  =  \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \mu\left( \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY} + \overset{\longrightarrow}{YZ}\right) = \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \mu\left( \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY} - \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX}\right) = (1 - \mu) \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \mu \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY} \qquad (2) $

$(1)$ and $(2)$ then give:

$$ (1 - \mu) \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \mu \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY} = \overset{\longrightarrow}{WP} = \lambda\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \lambda\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY},$$

and since $\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY}\ $ and $\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX}\ $ are not parallel, we may equate coefficients of $\ \mu\ $ and $\ \lambda\ $ to get that $\ \lambda = \mu = \frac{1}{2},\ $ and so $\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{WP} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \overset{\longrightarrow}{WX} + \ \overset{\longrightarrow}{XY} \right)\ = \frac{1}{2} \overset{\longrightarrow}{WY},\ $ and I'll leave it to you to show that therefore $\ \overset{\longrightarrow}{XP} = \frac{1}{2}\overset{\longrightarrow}{XZ}.$

Comment: This "since XY⟶  and  XY⟶  are not parallel" is a bit confusing.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. Now it's fixed...

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that just using PARALLELOGRAM LAW FOR VECTOR ADDITION

then two diagonals have the same midpoint.

So the conclusion must be that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcAWX.jpg

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, I recently still keep improving my basic knowledge on pure math probably because of desire to pursue PhD in math. And I also started listening to podcasts of neuroscience by Professor Andrew Huberman in past few weeks. Really appreciate your kind saying Hi. Here are many people who are passionate about math teaching and research. Just like those professors George Polya and his students James Stewart.